# Moment of inertia of solid cone

Tags: reference-frames, geometry, moment-of-inertia

[image: compressing square sheet into rod of same mass and length]Can we compress a solid cone parallel to the axis of rotation, into a disk of same mass to find moment of inertia of solid cone (uniformly dense)?

What I think...

As we are compressing the cone parallel to the axis the distance of every elemental point mass from the axis remain same...

Where i am wrong..?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It doesn't make sense (to me) to talk about the  the moment of inertia of a solid cone that's compressed into a solid disk (???)

Comment: What happened to the pictures? Please [edit] them back in as it is easier to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The MMOI for the two cases about the axis is not going to be the same.

My intuition is that the flat cone will have *half* the MMOI of a circular cone.

Let's figure it out, using cylindrical coordinatess $(r,\theta,z)$ to describe the interior of the shape:

- Radius of the cone at distance $z$ from the apex at *all* azimuth angles $\theta$

  $$r(z,\theta) =R \frac{z}{h} $$
- Volume integral for the regular cone of base radius $R$ and height $h$

  $$V^\text{circular} = \int_0^h \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{R \tfrac{z}{h}} r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}z = \tfrac{1}{3} \pi R^2 h\;\;\checkmark $$
- MMOI integral for regular cone of base  radius $R$ and height $h$ about the *z* axis

  $$I_{\rm zz}^\text{circular} = \tfrac{m}{V} \int_0^h \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{R \tfrac{z}{h}} (r^2) r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}z = \tfrac{3}{10} m R^2 \;\;\checkmark$$

Now we look at the squished cone and assign the squished dimension $b \rightarrow 0$. The cross-section is assumed to be that of an ellipse with section area at the base equal to $A = \pi R b$

- Radius of ellipse at distance $z$ from the apex, and azimuth angle $\theta$

  $$ r(z,\theta) = \frac{R b z}{h \sqrt{R^2-\cos^2 \theta (R^2-b^2)}}$$
- Volume integral for the regular cone of semi-major axis $R$, semi-minor axis $b$ and height $h$

  $$V^\text{squished} = \int_0^h \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{R b z}{h \sqrt{R^2-\cos^2 \theta (R^2-b^2)}}} r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}z = \tfrac{1}{3} \pi R b h $$
- MMOI integral for squished cone of semi-major axis $R$, semi-minor axis $b$ and height $h$ about the *z* axis

  $$I_{\rm zz}^\text{squished} = \tfrac{m}{V} \int_0^h \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{R b z}{h \sqrt{R^2-\cos^2 \theta (R^2-b^2)}}} (r^2) r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}z = \tfrac{3}{20} m (R^2+b^2) $$

Now take the limit $$ \lim_{b \rightarrow 0} I_{\rm zz}^\text{squished} = \tfrac{3}{20} m R^2$$ which is exactly half of the circular cone, exactly like I predicted.

---

NOTES: But the above **does not** preserve the density of the material. If you **do** want to preserve the density, then the semi-major axis of the cross-section will approach infinity as the semi-minor axis approaches zero. If you keep the *z* dimension $h$ constant, the net effect is the shape is described by

$$r(z,\theta) = \tfrac{b z R^2}{h\sqrt{R^2-\cos^2\theta (R^4-b^2)}}$$

with resulting MMOI

$$I_{\rm zz}^\text{flattened} = \tfrac{3 m (R^4+b^4)}{20 b^2}$$

Unfortunately, the limit of this when $b \rightarrow 0$ goes to $\infty$.

Intuitively to keep the same density if you squeeze along the *y* axis by 1/10 of the circular shape, then the dimensions along the *x* axis must be stretched by 10× to preserve the volume (and hence the density). So at fully flat, the other dimensions go to infinity, and any mass at infinity means infinite MMOI.

---

But the total height of the cone will be affected also in some way (realistically) and material along the axis does not contribute to the MMOI. So the MMOI is going to be finite. By how much, depends on the definition of the squished shape, as described by $r(z,\theta)$ as well as now $h(b)$.

A real material will expand along the *x* axis, as the *y* axis gets squished by $R \rightarrow b$. If you work out hook's law you can find that $R \rightarrow (1+\nu)R - \nu b$ along the *x* axis, and $h \rightarrow \frac{h((1+\nu)R-\nu b)}{R}$ along the *z* axis. Here $\nu$ is the Poisson's ratio and it is a value between 0.2 to 0.5. For steel this is $\nu=0.3$.

Use these values instead of $R$ and $h$ in the above to get

$$ V^\text{real} = \tfrac{ \pi b h (1+\nu) ((1+\nu)R -\nu b)^2}{3 (1+\nu) R} $$
$$ I_{\rm zz}^\text{real} = \tfrac{3}{20} m \left( b^2 + ( (1+\nu) R-\nu b)^2 \right)  $$

with the limit value for steel of

$$ I_{\rm zz}^\text{real} \approx 0.25 m R^2 $$

and compare this to the circular MMOI of

$$ I_{\rm zz}^\text{circular} = \tfrac{3}{10} m R^2 = 0.3 m R^2 $$

and you see that the real-life flattened cone has just a bit less the MMOI of a circular cone.

Interestingly for a material with $\nu = \sqrt{2}-1 = 0.412$ the two MMOI values are approximately the same. There are plenty of materials in the polymer category that would have this property.

Comment: See the update and discussion about what the squished shape looks like.

Comment: See the update now while estimating more of a real-life scenario which still does not preserve density, but follows hooks law of linear elasticity to find the MMOI of flattened cone.

Answer (score 0):

> As we are compressing the cone parallel to the axis the distance of every elemental point mass from the axis remain same...

You cant do that , lets say take a point on the top of the cone which is r distance away from a rotating axis , then if you compress the same cone down , there is no guarantee it will be same r distance from the axis.

The main thing is they are different shapes then compressing a shape to another still ends up with a new shape so you get a new Moment of inertia regardless you compress it or not
[image]